# How do I setup a keyboard mapping compatible with a Chromebook?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, chromebook, function-keys

Google's Chromebooks do not have standard keyboards. Ubuntu has a Mac layout, but no Chromebook layout. Help!

Keys that do no function correctly:

- All the F keys after F5
- All the "Media" keys below the F5 (back/forward/refresh)
- The every important "Search" key
- All the home/page down keys that should work with the arrow keys

Tested in Ubuntu 14.10 (Chrubuntu, not Crouton) on Intel HP Chromebook 14.

I hear the official package `xkb` has layouts you can edit in a complicated manner, but it is not clear how to map the new keys such as the "search" key.

Comment: Couldn't get this script to work http://www.reddit.com/r/chrubuntu/comments/1rsxkd/list_of_fixes_for_xubuntu_1310_on_the_acer_c720/ch74rbg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make media keys work on a Chromebook natively running Ubuntu MATE 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451097/how-to-make-media-keys-work-on-a-chromebook-natively-running-ubuntu-mate-22-04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Common Solution**

The best way to do this is with xmodmap
Use `xev` to find which keycode, and `xmodmap` to find which modifier, then add this to `~/.Xmodmap` and add the line `sleep 4 && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap &` to your `.bash_profile` to make sure it is ran on startup.

Add this to your `~/.Xmodmap`

```
clear mod4

!Make right alt to look like Super_R
!I'm assuming your search key has keycode 225, you can check using xev
keycode 225 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R

!Add the Super_L and Super_R keys to the modifier mod4
add mod4 = Super_L Super_R
```

**Alternate Solution**

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys-config xbindkeys xdotool
xbindkeys-config
```

Add this command to your xbindkeys-config when the search button is pressed:

`xdotool key Super`

When done, `~/.xbindkeyssrc should look something like this:

```
"xdotool key Super" 
    XF86Search
```

I don't know why you have to logout/log back in after doing this, but you do...

A bunch of other keys you can add are here:
http://www.reddit.com/r/chrubuntu/comments/1crefd/how_to_get_shortcut_keys_to_work_on_chrubuntu/

And here:
http://www.reddit.com/r/chrubuntu/comments/1rsxkd/list_of_fixes_for_xubuntu_1310_on_the_acer_c720/ce2ej5y

This may not work for many of the Window Handling commands (such as snap the window left, or view an overview of all your open windows (Super+W))

To set those, you'll need to go to Compiz Config Manager (`ccsm`) and change the Bindings there. Look in `Grid` and in `Scale` and in `Expo`