# How to make media keys work on a Chromebook running Ubuntu MATE or Kubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, mate, chromebook

I have [installed](https://askubuntu.com/q/1468964/124466) Ubuntu MATE 22.04 and Kubuntu 23.04 on two Chromebooks with `amd64` architecture.

The media keys are not working. I can change brightness from system settings, but the media keys are mapped to <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F10</kbd>.

How to make the media keys work?
Everything else works perfectly.

---

**Note**: The media keys work out of the box in [GalliumOS](https://galliumos.org/), but it is based on Xubuntu 18.04, and is not being actively developed anymore. I want to use the latest LTS version of Ubuntu in my Chromebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For recent (post 2020) Chromebooks that use the vivaldi driver, use the keyboard remapping script from the `cros-keyboard-map` repository by WeirdTreeThing.

```
git clone https://github.com/WeirdTreeThing/cros-keyboard-map
cd cros-keyboard-map
./install.sh
```

---

### **The rest of the answer is for chromebooks older than 2019.**

**Disclaimer**: This answer is partly based on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalliumOS/comments/nx25tq/install_chromebook_keyboard_on_ubuntu_and_debian/) Reddit post.
See [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1466776/124466) answer for GNOME.

### For **Ubuntu 22.04 and later versions**

In **Ubuntu MATE**, open keyboard settings, open the "Layouts" tab, and choose "Chromebook".

In **Kubuntu**, open `System Settings -> Input Devices -> Keyboard`, and choose `Google | Chromebook` as the layout.

[image]

---

### For Ubuntu 20.04 and previous versions, the workaround is to use GalliumOS keyboard layout.

First, download the .deb file for the keyboard layout.

```
wget https://apt.galliumos.org/pool/main/x/xkeyboard-config/xkb-data_2.23.1-1ubuntu1-galliumos1_all.deb
```

Now, install it.

```
sudo apt install ./xkb-data_2.23.1-1ubuntu1-galliumos1_all.deb
```

The latest version of `xkb-data` already has a Chromebook layout, but it is not as good as the GalliumOS layout, because the key for lowering brightness does not work there.

Therefore, you have to pin this particular version, so that it would not be overwritten by an update.

```
sudo apt-mark hold xkb_data
```

Then, open keyboard settings, and open the "Layouts" tab.

[image]

Choose the layout titled "Chromebook (most models) | Right alt overlay | F keys mapped to media keys". Here, the <kbd>alt</kbd> key acts as the "overlay" key (similar to the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key in usual laptop keyboards).

Finally, **reboot** your computer.

For more details about the keyboard layout, checkout [GalliumOS wiki](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Media_keys_and_default_keybindings).