# Ubuntu Chromebook numpad not working - Acer 315

Tags: uefi, mate, acer, chromebook

Hi my numpad is not working on Acer 315 Chromebook with Ubuntu Mate 22.04.02 Mrchromebox UEFI BIOS flash install. Everything else works great. The numpad, page up/down, home/end, and right enter key do not work. I have googled this issue and searched this site and can't find anything that works. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you choose the chromebook keyboard layout?https://askubuntu.com/a/1451098/124466

Comment: Yes. I only have one option under "Google" and that is "Chromebook"

Comment: I downloaded the GalliumOS keyboard layout, and Chromebook right alt overlay does not work as well. Will be testing several layouts from GOS.

Comment: Try opening an issue at https://github.com/MrChromebox/firmware/issues

Comment: Run the command `xev`. Do the numpad keys register any input?

Comment: I finally had some time to work on this, and I got the numpad to register input in xev by creating a custom keyboard layout in hwdb.d from this reddit thread. https://www.reddit.com/r/chrultrabook/comments/whtbjw/acer_chromebook_315_gemini_lake_blorb_numpad_issue/. Then I used input remapper gui to remap the keys to correct output. I now have a working numpad, pgup pgdown, enter etc. The only key that does not work is the fullscreen button, but I can live without it. Linux Mint XFCE installed and is 20x better than ChromeOS. Thank you for your help as well Archisman!!

Answer (score 2):

I got the numpad to register input in xev by creating a custom keyboard layout in hwdb.d from this reddit [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrultrabook/comments/whtbjw/acer_chromebook_315_gemini_lake_blorb_numpad_issue/). Then I used input remapper gui to remap the keys to correct output. I now have a working numpad, pgup pgdown, enter etc. The only key that does not work is the fullscreen button, but I can live without it. Linux Mint XFCE installed with working keys now.

Create the file `/usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/90-custom-keyboard.hwdb` with the following contents:

```
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svn*:pn*:pvr*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c9=pageup
 KEYBOARD_KEY_d1=pagedown
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c7=home
 KEYBOARD_KEY_cf=end
 KEYBOARD_KEY_d3=delete
 KEYBOARD_KEY_b5=kpslash
 KEYBOARD_KEY_37=kpasterisk
 KEYBOARD_KEY_4a=kpminus
 KEYBOARD_KEY_47=kp7
 KEYBOARD_KEY_48=kp8
 KEYBOARD_KEY_49=kp9
 KEYBOARD_KEY_4b=kp4
 KEYBOARD_KEY_4c=kp5
 KEYBOARD_KEY_4d=kp6
 KEYBOARD_KEY_4e=kpplus
 KEYBOARD_KEY_4f=kp1
 KEYBOARD_KEY_50=kp2
 KEYBOARD_KEY_51=kp3
 KEYBOARD_KEY_52=kp0
 KEYBOARD_KEY_53=kpdot
 KEYBOARD_KEY_9c=kpenter
```

then

```
sudo systemd-hwdb update
```