# How to use function keys on chromebook using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

Tags: 22.04, kubuntu, chromebook, google

I've been following different things by going to System Settings and going to Keyboard and changing the layout to "Google | Chromebook" but it didn't work.

I'm also using Kubuntu

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/q/1451097/124466

Comment: What is your Chromebook model?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Acer Chromebook 315

Answer (score -1):

You can use the keyboard remapping script from the `cros-keyboard-map` repository by WeirdTreeThing.

```
git clone https://github.com/WeirdTreeThing/cros-keyboard-map
cd cros-keyboard-map
./install.sh
```

It is an automated script that downloads and installs the keyboard remapping tool [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) and configures the appropriate keyboard layout for your chromebook.

Comment: i tried doing the search key then the corresponding function key but it didn't work

Comment: Do the other function keys work? You may have to remap the search key in keyboard shortcuts in KDE settings.

Comment: how do i remap the search key?

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with the script but i'll press a key once not trying to spam the letter but then it will repeat the letter again without me wanting to